# Logical "NOT" in SearchCriteria

Tags: magento2, rest-api, search-criteria, repository

I found how to use logical "AND" & "OR" in search criteria:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html

How to use logical "NOT" in filters/filters groups?

Comment: you mean `neq`?

Comment: I mean `WHERE NOT ((param1 = 8 AND param2 = 7) OR (param3 = 6 AND param4 = 5))`